# Generic List of ListViewItems

Tags: c#, listviewitem

Sorry for the title, I couldn't think of a more descriptive/succinct way to convey my problem.

My problem is that I have a function which operates on a collection of ListViewItems via a foreach-loop, and the list of items it will operate on depends on a boolean parameter to the function, call it **bSelected**.

If this is true, I want to use the SelectedItems from my list view, otherwise I want to use the Items from the list view.

I'm having trouble determining what this object representing the list of items should be, or how to get it. I've tried a couple different approaches (Note the ListView is called **lvList**):

```
IList<ListViewItem> listItems = 
  ( bSelected ? (IList<ListViewItem>)lvList.SelectedItems 
              : (IList<ListViewItem>)lvList.Items );
foreach ( ListViewItem lvi in listItems ) { ... }
```

and

```
IEnumerator<ListViewItem> listEnumerator = 
  ( bSelected ? (IEnumerator<ListViewItem>)lvList.SelectedItems.GetEnumerator() 
              : (IEnumerator<ListViewItem>)lvList.Items.GetEnumerator() );
while ( listEnumerator.MoveNext() ) { ... }
```

I've tried other solutions of a similar ilk, but I get run-time errors having to do with type conversions applied to the SelectedItems.

I know that there's got to be a way, since using foreach loops directly on one list or the other works, i.e.:

```
foreach ( ListViewItem lvi in lvList.SelectedItems ) { ... }
```

and

```
foreach ( ListViewItem lvi in lvList.Items ) { ... }
```

I don't have much C# experience, so help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could force it to be a strongly typed List like this:

```
List<ListViewItem> listItems = 
  ( bSelected ? lvList.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().ToList()
              : lvList.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().ToList() );
```

Go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) for more info on `Cast`

Answer (score 1):

Try using untyped untyped IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable listEnumerable = 
  ( bSelected ? lvList.SelectedItems 
              : lvList.Items);
foreach ( ListViewItem lvi in listEnumerable ) { ... }
```

Comment: Alex, you can probably drop the casts as well as the "GetEnumerator".

Comment: and I think it should be IEnumerable<ListViewItem>, though I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: IEnumerable<ListViewItem> is a descendant of plain IEnumerable

Comment: this doesn't compile either, it wants a type with IEnumerator

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IList as they both implement it.  Try the following:

```
IList listItems = 
  ( bSelected ? (IList)lvList.SelectedItems 
              : (IList)lvList.Items );
foreach ( ListViewItem lvi in listItems ) { ... }
```

Comment: it doesn't compile, it wants a type with the list

Comment: Hi Sean, apologies but I have just tried it again and it is working in VS 2010 on 4.0.  Would you mind telling me which version of VS\.Net you are using?

Comment: VS 2010, .NET 4.505079 according to "About Microsoft Visual Studio"

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, it says they are of type `ListViewItemCollection`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx

Comment: yeah that was one of the thing I tried but didn't mention... I get a run-time error: Unable to cast object of type 'SZArrayEnumerator' to type 'ListViewItemCollection'.